# Is it possible to manipulate an element before inserting it into the DOM with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I know this has been asked already but it has never really been elaborated upon. I want to insert an element into the DOM in my page, but only after constructing it out-with the DOM. I know it is possible, but it seems that this feature only partially works. For example...

```
// this doesnt work
var theDiv = '<div></div>';
$(theDiv).append('<p>test</p>');
alert($(theDiv).html());

// this works
var theDiv = '<div></div>';
alert($(theDiv).html());
```

I hope someone can shed some light on this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The reason this does not work as intended is because you are creating a new jQuery object each time.

```
var theDiv = '<div></div>';
$(theDiv).append('<p>test</p>');  //Create a new jquery object and append a p
alert($(theDiv).html());  //create a new jquery object of just a div and output the html
```

If you want to fix this issue you simply just need to create a new variable to hold your jQuery object.

```
var theDiv = '<div></div>';
var $d = $(theDiv).append('<p>test</p>'); //create a new jQuery object and than append 
                                          //a p and store it in a variable
alert($d.html());  //output the contents of the variable's html
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/YtnR6/).**

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var theDiv = $('<div/>');
theDiv.append('<p>test</p>');
alert(theDiv.html());
```

Comment: I'm not much of a jquery guy but, doesn't the framework create the closing tag for you?

Comment: @Mark: I thought jQuery would create the closing tag... Edited!

Comment: @Stephen I thought it'd do... But @Mark thinks it doesn't... Both work   I guess

Comment: See the discussion here: http://api.jquery.com/after/ for "some" of the source of my thought pattern on this re: "<div><div>" and working with nodes and not strings from Karl re: "insert well formed xhtml".

Comment: I DO like this solution better than creating variables, and it does work in my tests.  Beware also that empty or self closing elements do not always work in IE xhtml documents however.